# Consul treats my folders as keys

Tags: consul

When requesting a list of keys from Consul, the current folder gets returned as a key:

http://consul_url/v1/kv/app/myapp?keys

["app/myapp/key1","app/myapp/key2","app/myapp/key3","app/myapp/key4","app/myapp/"]

when checking another app/ folder, it doesn't:

["app/myapp2/key1","app/myapp2/key2","app/myapp2/key3","app/myapp2/key4","app/myapp2/"]

I would like the folder to not show up in the list of keys.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior - each path member is a key and can have an associated value. You cannot have "just folder" keys.

However, the path there (`/app/myapp`) is a prefix when using `?keys`, so if you leave out the trailing slash, that might be causing the behavior you see.